# I am trying to convert a string to efficient xml using nagasena example but i get a runtime error

Tags: java

```java
private static void encode(String sourceFile) throws FileNotFoundException,       IOException, EXIOptionsException, TransmogrifierException {
String sCurrentLine=null;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sourceFile))){

while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
sb.append(sCurrentLine);
}

}
String sb1= sb.toString();

System.out.println("xml to string:"+sb1+"\n");

OutputStream out =null;
//this code from nagasena

GrammarCache grammarCache;
Transmogrifier transmogrifier = new Transmogrifier();
grammarCache = new GrammarCache(GrammarOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
transmogrifier.setGrammarCache(grammarCache);
transmogrifier.setOutputStream(out);
//passing the string as input    
transmogrifier.encode(new InputSource(sb1));
System.out.println("Check2 : String to EXI conversion"+ out +"\n");
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Data><String translate="yes"> &lt;b&gt;SDL Trados Studio 2009 SP1&lt;/b&gt;&lt;span class="highlight"&gt;revolutionary software&lt;/span&gt; on the market.  </String></Data>
 at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:586)
 at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
 at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)